# Sinon spy not registering

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon

What's the correct syntax for this?

```
// In source-code
function Foo() {
    var bar = new Bar();
}

// In tests
var spy = sinon.spy(Bar);
var foo = new Foo();
console.log(spy.callCount);
```

I expect spy.callCount to be 1, but it is 0.

Is this possible without modifying the source?

Comment: http://www.hiddentao.com/archives/2013/06/10/mocking-calls-to-a-class-constructor-in-javascript/

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the example to be a bit more complex. I'm not sure this is even possible after reading your link.

Comment: I don't think so either, at least not as-is. [Here's](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sinonjs/vwM1OEPjo60) another relevant page.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the links anyway. I guess a semi-workaround could be to have a single line proxy to Bar() as a method on Foo, then test against that.

Comment: Actually, namespacing is probably cleaner :-)